# Resources don't link with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have java project and files in folder:  src->main->resources->some files .
I don't link my resources with gradle build

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

application {
    mainClassName = "com.nameless.Main"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.nameless.Main'
    }
    baseName = 'web_file_server'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Remove all you have posted from your gradle file. The correct directory is src/main/resources, and it's the default location for resources, so you don't need to specify anything. Then explain what you mean by "I don't link my resources". Be precise. Tell what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Post the relevant code and errors.

Comment: @JBNizet when I run gradle build I expect that my project will start, however, when it starts, resources will not be connected. It don't see them and my project give me exception

Comment: Paste us a log please.

Comment: @amer java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/login.html (No such file or directory)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

Comment: and also when I start my_project.sh in folder "build". It give error:  Error: Could not find or load main class com.nameless.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nameless.Main

Comment: @JBNizet https://github.com/midaef/web_file_server

Comment: Ref: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa/blob/master/build.gradle#L65

Comment: You're using file IO to access classpath resources. That's the problem. Use Class[Loader].getResource[AsStream]. You didn't post any code, and the stack trace is partial. Edit your question, and post the code and the stack trace.